# webpack-dev-server inconsistencies when migrating from v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, webpack, migration, webpack-dev-server

After upgrading `webpack-dev-server` from v3 to v4, I found two odd inconsistencies.

1. webpack-dev-server `publicPath` does not work anymore, without pairing it with [the new static option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverstatic).

   - In the past, this was enough to make things work:

   ```js
   {
     // ...
     devServer: {
       publicPath: '/'
     }
   }
   ```

   - But now this is required instead:

   ```js
   {
     // ...
     devServer: {
       devMiddleware: {
         publicPath: '/'
       },
       static: [
         {
           directory: context.replace(/\//g, '\\'),
           publicPath: '/'
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
2. The second problem is also visible in the code above. You can see in the new version above that my `context` has a weird hack: I have to replace forward slashes with backward slashes on Windows - `context.replace(/\//g, '\\')`. If I don't do that, I am punished by an inaccurate `URL` detection algorithm. Since forward slashes are perfectly fine on Windows, it should not complain about it not being a directory. Windows' own tools all think it is a directory, but `webpack-dev-server` does not:

   ```
   Error: Using a URL as static.directory is not supported
       at getStaticItem (c:\thecode\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:557:15)
       at c:\thecode\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:1046:16
       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
       at Server.normalizeOptions (c:\thecode\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:1041:39)
       at Server.start (c:\thecode\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:2252:16)
       at Command.<anonymous> (c:\thecode\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js:242:38)
       at async Promise.all (index 1)
       at async Command.<anonymous> (c:\thecode\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1672:7)
   ```

My setup:

```yaml
webpack: 5
OS: Windows 10
Node: 16
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Is that documented/expected behavior? Or is it something I should file on their Github issue page?

**Workaround for (2)**: the URL problem can be fixed via `path.resolve`. I.e.: `directory: path.resolve(context)`.